# Reordering cells in UITableView takes out functionality of cells in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

I am using JSON to parse data from Spotify and add songs into a UITableView. The songs play fine, and I added functionality for deleting cells, but when adding functionality for reording cells, I can''t play songs and I can't swipe to delete them either. Any ideas would be appreciated.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.



    self.tableView.isEditing = true


    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return posts.count

}
```

This adds the album image and song name to the TableView.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell")
    let mainImageView = cell?.viewWithTag(2) as! UIImageView
    mainImageView.image = posts[indexPath.row].mainImage
    let mainLabel = cell?.viewWithTag(1) as! UILabel
    mainLabel.text = posts[indexPath.row].name
    return cell!
}
```

This adds the swipe to delete functionality.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete {
        posts.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
    } else if editingStyle == .insert {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view.
    }
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editingStyleForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell.EditingStyle {
    return .none
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, shouldIndentWhileEditingRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return false
}
```

This adds the reordering functionality.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {
    let movedObject = self.posts[sourceIndexPath.row]
    posts.remove(at: sourceIndexPath.row)
    posts.insert(movedObject, at: destinationIndexPath.row)
    debugPrint("\(sourceIndexPath.row) => \(destinationIndexPath.row)")
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: try to reload tableview in main thread.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to set

`self.tableView.isEditing = true`

in viewDidLoad.  This takes you from the "normal" mode where you can select a cell, or other elements in a cell.  Setting "self.tableview.isEditing" is the equivalent of hitting an edit button on the top right-hand corner of many tableViews.